# Angular nvd3 bar chart: how to limit the number of bars to be displayed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, bar-chart, nvd3.js

I use angular nvd3 directives to create a multi bar chart. My data input has lots of values. I would like to display only the last 20 values on the bar chart. This would limit the number of bars and would render the bar chart more readable.
Is there a way to only display a range of values on the chart?

Thank you!

Code looks like this:

```
   <nvd3-multi-bar-chart
            data="exampleData"
            id="exampleId"
            showXAxis="false"
            showYAxis="true"
            xAxisTickFormat="xAxisTickFormatFunction()"
            yAxisTickFormat="yAxisTickFormatFunction()"
            width="550"
            height="400"
            tooltips="true"
            interactive="true"
            showLegend="true"
            rotateLabels="40"   
            >
        <svg></svg>
</nvd3-multi-bar-chart>

<script type="text/javascript">
     var app = angular.module("nvd3TestApp", ['nvd3ChartDirectives']);  
      function ExampleCtrl($scope){

          $scope.exampleData = [{
              "key": "Active STBs Count",
              "color": "#1f77b4",
              "values": [[1414432801855,  3],
                        [1414436401526,  3], ...]
          },];
          $scope.xAxisTickFormatFunction = function(){
              return function(d){
                return d3.time.format('%H:%M')(new Date(d));
              }
          }

          $scope.yAxisTickFormatFunction = function(){
              return function(d){
                 return d3.format(',d')(d);
              }
            };
          }              
    </script>
```

[image: The bar chart:]

Comment: why you don't just preprocess your exampleData to have only last twenty records?

Comment: Thanks @huanfeng! Actually, I had the same idea which is practical but I was wondering if there is also another solution. Till then I will go with this solution :) Thanks again